# Building Neural Networks [TensorFlow 2.0] Model sub-classing - ValueError/TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am using TensorFlow 2.0 with Python 3.7.5 to build a neural network for Iris classification using Model sub-classing approach.

The code I have is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Read in data-
data = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

# Get data types for different attributes-
data.dtypes
'''
sepallength    float64
sepalwidth     float64
petallength    float64
petalwidth     float64
class           object
dtype: object
'''


# Get shape of data-
data.shape
# (150, 5)


# Check for missing values-
data.isnull().values.any()
# False

# Perform label encoding for target variable-

# Initialize a label encoder-
le = LabelEncoder()

# Label encode target attribute-
data['class'] = le.fit_transform(data['class'])

# Get different classes which are label encoded-
le.classes_
# array(['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica'], dtype=object)

# Split data into features (X) and target (y)-
X = data.drop('class', axis = 1)
y = data['class']


# Get training & testing sets using features and labels-
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

# Convert from Pandas to numpy arrays-
X_train = X_train.to_numpy()
X_test = X_test.to_numpy()

y_train = y_train.to_numpy()
y_test = y_test.to_numpy()

print("\nTraining and Testing set dimensions:")
print("X_train.shape = {0}, y_train.shape = {1}".format(X_train.shape, y_train.shape))
print("X_test.shape = {0}, y_test.shape = {1}\n".format(X_test.shape, y_test.shape))
# Training and Testing set dimensions:
# X_train.shape = (105, 4), y_train.shape = (105,)
# X_test.shape = (45, 4), y_test.shape = (45,)



class IrisClassifier(Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(IrisClassifier, self).__init__()

        '''
        self.layer1 = Dense(
            units = 4, activation = 'relu',
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
            )
        '''

        self.input_layer = Input(
            shape = (4,)
            )

        self.layer1 = Dense(
            units = 10, activation = 'relu',
            input_dim = 4,
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
            )

        self.layer2 = Dense(
            units = 10, activation = 'relu',
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
            )

        self.outputlayer = Dense(
            units = 3, activation = 'softmax'
            )


    def call(self, x):
        x = self.input_layer(x)
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        # x = self.layer3(x)

        return self.outputlayer(x)


# Instantiate a model of defined neural network class-
model = IrisClassifier()

# Define EarlyStopping callback-
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)

# Compile defined model-
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001),
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics = ['accuracy']
     )


# Train model-
history2 = model.fit(
    x = X_train, y = y_train,
    validation_data = [X_test, y_test],
    epochs = 50, batch_size = 16,
    callbacks = [callback]
    )
```

When I execute 'history2' code, I get the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         3         validation_data = [X_test, y_test],
>         4         epochs = 50, batch_size = 16,
>   ----> 5         callbacks = [callback]
>         6   )
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
>   **kwargs)
>       726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>       727         workers=workers,
>   --> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>       729 
>       730   def evaluate(self,
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py
>   in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   validation_freq, **kwargs)
>       640         steps=steps_per_epoch,
>       641         validation_split=validation_split,
>   --> 642         shuffle=shuffle)
>       643 
>       644     if validation_data:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
>   batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle,
>   extract_tensors_from_dataset)    2417     # First, we build the model
>   on the fly if necessary.    2418     if not self.inputs:
>   -> 2419       all_inputs, y_input, dict_inputs = self._build_model_with_inputs(x, y)    2420       is_build_called =
>   True    2421     else:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in _build_model_with_inputs(self, inputs, targets)    2580     # or
>   lists of arrays, and extract a flat list of inputs from the passed
>   2581     # structure.
>   -> 2582     training_utils.validate_input_types(inputs, orig_inputs)    2583     2584     if isinstance(inputs, (list, tuple)):
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py
>   in validate_input_types(inp, orig_inp, allow_dict, field_name)    1149
>   raise ValueError(    1150         'Please provide as model inputs
>   either a single array or a list of '
>   -> 1151         'arrays. You passed: {}={}'.format(field_name, orig_inp))    1152     1153
>
> ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a
>   list of arrays. You passed: inputs=     sepallength  sepalwidth 
>   petallength  petalwidth 117          7.7         3.8          6.7
>   2.2 7            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2 73           6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 92           5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 87           6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 ..           ...         ...          ...         ... 93           5.0
>   2.3          3.3         1.0 30           4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2 25           5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2 31           5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4 97           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3
>
> [105 rows x 4 columns]

After converting X_train, y_train, X_test and y_test to numpy arrays, when I execute, history2 to train the model, I get the following error:

TypeError: in converted code:

> ```
> <ipython-input-14-ae6111e00410>:34 call  *
>     x = self.input_layer(x)
> /home/arjun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py:427
> ```
>
> converted_call
>           f in m.**dict**.values() for m in (collections, pdb, copy, inspect, re)):
>       /home/arjun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py:427
>   
>           f in m.**dict**.values() for m in (collections, pdb, copy, inspect, re)):
>       /home/arjun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py:1336
>   tensor_equals
>           return gen_math_ops.equal(self, other)
>       /home/arjun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py:3627
>   equal
>           name=name)
>       /home/arjun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py:536
>   _apply_op_helper
>           repr(values), type(values).**name**, err))
>
> ```
> TypeError: Expected float32 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Equal', got 'collections' of type 'str' instead. Error: Expected float32, got
> ```
>
> 'collections' of type 'str' instead.

What's going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the way you preprocess your data, before you fit it to your model.

It is highly likely that you pass the entire csv-dataset from iris, including your column headers, hence your issue. You can verify this from

> "You passed: inputs= sepallength sepalwidth petallength petalwidth 117
>   7.7 3.8 6.7".

Ensure that your Xs and ys do not contain the column names, but only the values. Use `X_train = X_train.to_numpy()` to ensure the conversion works. In older versions, you could also use `X_train.values`, but the latter has been deprecated.

Comment: Please at least vote since it solved your first problem. Please ask another question if you have another issue, rather than having a chain of questions in a single one. Thank you.

Comment: it's not a series of questions. After I converted training and testing sets to numpy (as you suggested), I get a new error viz., *TypeError*

Comment: I haven't run in the last issue up until now, I am currently researching to help you

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. According to Francois Chollet:

> A subclassed model is a piece of Python code (a call method). There is
>   no graph of layers here. We cannot know how layers are connected to
>   each other (because that's defined in the body of call, not as an
>   explicit data structure), so we cannot infer input / output shapes

Therefore, the following code runs fine (where you don't specify the input training data shape):

```
# Define EarlyStopping callback-
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)

class IrisClassifier(Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(IrisClassifier, self).__init__()

        self.layer1 = Dense(
            units = 10, activation = 'relu',
            # input_dim = 4,
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
            )

        self.layer2 = Dense(
            units = 10, activation = 'relu',
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
            )

        self.outputlayer = Dense(
            units = 3, activation = 'softmax'
            )


    def call(self, x):
        # x = self.input_layer(x)
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        # x = self.layer3(x)
        return self.outputlayer(x)


# Instantiate a model of defined neural network class-
model2 = IrisClassifier()


# Compile defined model-
model2.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001),
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics = ['accuracy']
     )


# Train model-
history2 = model2.fit(
    x = X_train, y = y_train,
    validation_data = [X_test, y_test],
    epochs = 50, batch_size = 16,
    callbacks = [callback]
    )
```

Thanks!

Comment: I gave you a similar response on your other question if you pay attention. Good that you solved the problem. :D

Comment: I was looking for the explanation as I quoted in my answer as this gives clarity. But, thanks! :D